# What website for posting writing is going to give me the least grief?

Tags: publishing

So, for all of you who post your stories online, you may know my pain.

For those who don't, I'd like to post some of my writing online on sites such as Deviantart and Wattpad. However, I've been receiving a lot of grief for each and every site I go to.

I know most of it is assumptions and stereotypes, but does anyone know a site that I can post to that won't get my work criticized and disregarded for it's placement?

This isn't about how much criticism I'm going to get from users on that site, but more about how people in real life are going to view me if I post on x site.

Comment: Have you considered a personal blog site? Simple things like wordpress, squarespace... and registering your own domain eventually (if you wanted that), isn't too pricey either.

Comment: Well, personally, I don't have enough to even afford that.

Comment: I think this might be a bit subjective. I've been a member of deviantArt since 2006 and I don't recall ever receiving a single negative comment (though having said that, I barely receive any comments at all there). My most scathing feedback has been on FictionPress/FanFiction.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the stuff I've got there. But still, when I talk irl about websites, that's when things get sticky.

Comment: In any case (I also have never registered my own domain), using wordpress even with the .wordpress isn't much different from using a platform like deviantArt. It may also help avoid stereotypes you mentioned when you chat irl. I used blogspot for a long time.

Comment: Wordpress is generally free and there are other free blogging sites.  You may want a site designed for posting one's work so it gets more eyeballs, but money shouldn't be a consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question**: "does anyone know a site that I can post to that won't get my work criticized and disregarded for it's placement?"

**Answer:** Yes. If you join Critters.org you will not get the sort of grief you describe from other sites. It's a semi-professional site with certain requirements that have the effect of dissuading any 'fan fiction' type dynamics.

It is meant for serious original content writers. Chances are, no one in your real world has heard of it, but it is very active nonetheless. No one would give you grief.

Comment: I was happy reading another serious site for fiction, and sad reading its not available for europeans :(

Answer (score 4):

As a writer if you want to share your work with people at large you need to develop a very thick skin.

The nature and to a certain extent culture of the internet in particular means that people feel little to no compunction to wrap what they say in polite niceties which is very different than what they may say to someone in a more personal setting such as face to face. And of course there is always the problem of trolls.

Remember that no creative work that has gained sufficient exposure to be discussed on line escapes this. *Everything,* from the *Avengers* movies to *Harry Potter*, from the Lord of the Rings, to the works of celebrated literary greats like Shakespere will have recieved a sound drubbing at the hands of the internet commentariat.

While this might *sound* like a reason not to do it - there is also going to be plenty of valuable things you can learn from feedback (even if it's negative). It's about learning to spot the difference between the things you want to take on board and the things you want to just discard as so much noise. Here's some hypothetical examples (but of the sort of thing I've genuinely seen in various places)

> The ending was rubbish - I don't get why [Character X] did this at the end.. it just makes no sense based on everything they did up to this point!

^ this is actually good feedback and worth looking into - maybe you act on it and change the way you do thing in future or maybe not. This person has clearly read to the end though. Even if they didn't like what you did at the end they still got there.

> Got bored half way through and gave up! ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ!

^ OK this is a little less constructive - but if enough people make similar comments then perhaps you're losing readers in the middle? Do you need to look at bringing the pace up a notch?

> This f##king sux!

^ Noise, you can't learn anything useful from it so just ignore it.

> [Author] is an idiot. WTF is this dross?

^ Noise, you can't learn anything useful from it so just ignore it.

So be brave.. post your stuff wherever it's on-topic and see what comes back, just remember to filter out the noise!

**Edit: Addressing the OP's concerns about "real" life criticism for site choices**

I think this aspect is perhaps more in the [interpersonal](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) domain than writing *per se* but since we're here.. human nature means it's harder to just shrug off any "grief" you may get for your choice of publishing venue - but I do have to think that if you're getting rude comments from people about this sort of thing then why talk to them about it? In fact, why talk to them at all, they don't sound like people particularly worth talking to. Such comments say far more about their character then it does about you or your writing.

Comment: Well, I don't really care about the comments on said sites. I'm more worried about the placement of my stories irl will give me flak, like "OH, you post on Deviantart? Only 12 year old cringy fanfic writers post there!" and such. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: @KaleSlade that was completely not obvious from your question.  You might want to edit the question and state "edited to clarify" or something.  Just do it in a way that doesn't invalidate motosubatsu's answer.

Comment: @KaleSlade it might help if you could provide some context about where you are talking about this and to what sort of person. Is this at a writers group or similar?

Answer (score 1):

#### The only way to not be criticized, is to not share.

If you must post, put it to a Dropbox or Drive account and then make select content shareable with temp links to select people. Control who can see it, and you control who can criticize it.

---

Your other realistic option is to create a site that allows a certain amount of space for free or cheap, and grants you control over content. A WordPress site had already been mentioned, which basic version is free. This is what I use, personally.

A BB  forum site is another option that I've seen.

Amino will likely have a group niche site somewhere that happens to cater to your taste. But you won't have much control unless you start your own.

Any option of these three requires some learning to adjust to the format, and the control schemes.